# Android Pre-installed system app with device administrator permission?

Tags: android, device, mdm, administrator

I am building an pre-installed MDM app for OEM use case where app will be pre-installed on the device. One of the requirements is that this app should not require any manual set up. I have not found a way yet to activate device administrator programmatically. Is there any API or permission that can be added in manifest to do this?

Is it possible to programatically enabled an android app device administrator access given the fact it will be pre-installed as system app and signed with same key as firmware?

It will be great if someone can point me in right direction or let me know if its feasible or not. App, will be installed as system app and can be signed with same key as firmware. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to programatically enabled an android app device administrator access given the fact it will be pre-installed as system app and signed with same key as firmware?

Comment: @AADTechnical - the question is quite clear.  Perhaps you are unfamiliar with the subject matter?   As for an answer, ultimately, the answer is yes, but the more interesting question is can it be done by a means short of modifying the source of the Android components which handle this.